# How to create an Evernote kind of widget for global menu of a MacOS/X desktop using QT?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, user-interface

How to create an application which stays in top of MacOS, something similar to below image. You can see the `Evernote elephant icon`. [image]

I don't want to use `xcode` - because my application already built in QT, it has nice GUI, now I wanted to add extended feature something similar to Evernote.  If I click on an elephant it will open a dialog box to write notes. In my case- it's a simple event like on/off buttons. [image]

I have tried and created GUI widget apps but how to make one which resides like Evernote app ?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @pvg - I think it's not spam and also it's not opinion question because I am asking what to use to make one something like Evernote app? So far I just know how to create simple GUI but not the complex one such as the one which I mentioned here.

Comment: Nothing there says your question is spam. Please read the linked docs. This kind of question is just not on topic on [SO], the docs explain why.

Comment: I refined the question , I think now it makes more sense ? @pvg

Comment: You may be looking for a [system tray icon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a program written for Qt, then you can compile and run it under MacOS/X much the same way you could compile it under (whatever OS you're using now).  You'll need to install Xcode because Xcode includes the C++ compiler (clang) you'll need in order to compile your Qt program, but you don't have to use the Xcode IDE if you don't want to.  Rather, you can either use the QtCreator IDE under MacOS/X, or you can simply open up a Terminal window and do a "qmake ; make" in the directory where your Qt-based program's .pro file is, and build it from the command line that way.

If, on the other hand, your question is actually about how to add an icon to the global menu of a MacOS/X desktop, then I don't think Qt has an API for that, so you'll need to drop down to using one of MacOS/X's native APIs.  That will probably involve learning some Objective-C (or Objective-C++, if you prefer), but integrating a bit of Objective-C/C++ into your Qt app is doable with a bit of work.

Answer (score 1):

A custom pop up menu like the one pictured can be done several ways in Qt.

`QML` is the most modern way of making the menu with the customized styling you are looking for.

Apply the appropriate flags to the window/widget so it appears as a popup.

The same effects can also be done in `QWidgets`, but takes more code and probably will take longer to make.  The flags you are looking for will be found under Qt Window Flags and/or under Qt Widget Attributes.

The stock stylings for Qt for different OS's deal mostly with title bars, status bars, buttons, drop downs, etc.

The base styles for Mac can be found here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gallery-macintosh.html

Once you go to a customized popup, you have to draw all of it yourself... but the native drawing elements in Qt are friendly enough and get you that look you are trying to do.

There are even some tools for exporting from Photoshop or Gimp directly to QML.

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/quick-export-to-qml.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a tray icon. Qt implements it in [`QSystemTrayIcon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html).

**Further information**

- You may take a look at the [System Tray Icon Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html).
- Many [StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqt%5D%20tray%20icon) exist on this topic.